# Is there any way I can view old npm package online through browser?

Tags: npm

I know that I can list all old versions of certain npm package through command line. However is there a way that I can view a certain version of npm package just from website? e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis@2.00

Basically, I want to check how the old version's instruction and its own dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on npm but you can on github:

1. Go to the package's npm link
2. Click on the github (or bitbucket etc.) link for the package (on the right)
3. On github click the "Branch:" drop-down
4. Select the "Tags" tab in the drop-down
5. Select the version you want

To see dependencies open the project's package.json file